Word synonyms free dataset as high quality as Google definitions?
Google has lots of synonyms for almost every basic word. I checked WordNet and the data is quite messy and hard to work with, and it doesn't appear to be organized quite this cleanly and robustly as Google's (Oxford-borrowed) dictionary term synonyms.
Do we have this data available for free anywhere, or anything on par or near close to it in terms of quality and thoroughness, for English?

